# How to connect to Mantis on Synology NAS at work?

Tags: networking, nas, synology

I have configured Mantis (bugtracker web application) on my Synology NAS using the Package Center. I can reach it via my local (home) network via http://192.168.0.58/mantisbt/, however: how do I reach it from my work location (my NAS is at home)? What do I type in the URL bar? What do I need to configure? What is the easiest way to configure this? Can someone help me?

How can I configure my NAS that when I type in my address bar "http://synas.john.nl" for example, that I go to my NAS? I have a domain name.

Note: I am a complete newbie at this. I know how port forwarding works and how to configure it, how to configure a (NodeJS) server etc. but that's a bit how far my network engineering knowledge goes.

Comment: well, if you know how to port forward, and the service is already accessible internally, then all you need is DNS. you have a domain, so port forward 192.168.0.58:80 to your WAN on port 80, and then point your domain name to your public IP address. I'm guessing your domain registration is handled by a service, so you will have to have them update it (or use the tools they offer to do it yourself). You may have to configure the webservice a little, but that's all Mantis configuration.

Comment: @FrankThomas So when i configure port forwarding for my router to point to 192.168.0.58:80, i can then type (for example) "http://[my public ip / my domain]:80/mantisbt"? Then it will go to 192.168.0.58:80/mantisbt? Is that with everything? So when i configure a NodeJS server on port 3000, then when i type [public ip]:3000 then it will go to my nodejs server?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yup, it works, when I type in my public IP, it shows Mantis: however with an error message: APPLICATION ERROR #400
Database connection failed. Error received from database was #0: PHP Support for database is not enabled.
Please use the "Back" button in your web browser to return to the previous page. There you can correct whatever problems were identified in this error or select another action. You can also click an option from the menu bar to go directly to a new section. How do I solve this? Thanks for the help earlier btw :)

Comment: ok, that is a somewhat differant question. what version of PHP, and which version of Mantis?

Comment: yes you could forward whatever port you want on the WAN, and specify it in the url as you describe, to access a service on a server inside your LAN. as for your database error, does mantis work correctly from inside your network?

Comment: @FrankThomas I have PHP 7.0.16 and Mantis version 1.2.19. The error I got was from another mantis "app" that i tried to install that has the same PHP and Mantis version. When I now try to reach mantis via "[public ip]/mantisbt", it says "mantisbt:1 Refused to display 'http://[public ip]/mantisbt/login_page.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
[public ip]/mantisbt/login_page.php Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE"

On my domain name, i configured the domain with a frame forwarding.

Internally, everything works fine. Even over VPN.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59534/discussion-between-johnnybossboy-and-frank-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the QuickConnect feature of your Synology as it is the easiest way to do this.  Summon QuickConnect from the Synology Control Panel, under the Connectivity section.  You will have to register for an Synology QuickConnect account and elect a QuickConnect ID so that you can connect to your Synology NAS from anywhere as long as it has a direct connection to the internet.  The QuickConnect Synology service is a third-party relay offered by Synology and you will have your MantisBT connection to something like:

http://yourqcid.synoregionalserver18.quickconnect.to/mantisbt/